# Как цитировать современных авторов?

Tags: цитата

Проблема возникает, когда сильный объективный фактор, в нашем случае это снижение цены на нефть и санкции, ведут к тому, что стратегии становятся абсолютно однонаправленными.

Наверное, надо писать *ведет*, даже если цитируемый говорит *ведут*?

Это "Новая газета" цитирует "Интерфакс".
Должен ли был "Интерфакс" поправить Набиулину?
Должна "Новая газета" цитировать "Интерфакс" слово в слово?

Comment: Возможно друг с другом договориться. Все зависит от редактора газеты.

Comment: В данном случае интервью, вероятно, давалось в устной форме, и записанное следовало отредактировать первому его разместившему. Здесь, скорее, нужно множественное число в выражении "сильные объективные факторы", что говорившей сложно было предусмотреть: по ходу фразы вспомнился второй важный фактор.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы цитируете кого-нибудь автора, исправлять ошибки в цитате не стоит. В таких случаях обычно пишут (sic), что означает: ошибка автора приведенной цитаты и вы за ошибку не отвечаете.